# How do I enable automatic stacking for mobile?

Tags: mobile

I've put in a row of blocks but when I view the blocks from mobile it stretches them out instead of stacking them. I've been playing around with it but I can't seem to make it work.

Comment: To answer this question, much more information is needed. Please provide as much information as possible, for example: which theme are you using?, What is the problem in your css? What have you tried so far? What is the HTML markup? etc. if you expect the community to help you.